# How to check for continuous column count via datatable?

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I have a datatable below and I wanted to check the condition if the latest columns have total count of more then 7 then the function will do something but my current solution is only able to count the number of 1 in the datatable but unable to identify the value 1 is consecutive from column 7 to column 14.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Id  | 1  | 2  | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
kek | 1  | 0  | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |  1 | 1  |  1 |  1 |  1 |
```

Solution

```
Sub CheckExtraday()
    Dim count1 As Integer = 0
    Dim sql As String = "Select * from LeaveSystem WHERE EmpID ='" + Session("empID") + "' and Year='" + Session("year") + "' and Month='" + Session("month") + "'"

    Dim dt As DataTable = getDTms(sql)
    For I As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
        For k As Integer = 2 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
            If dt.Rows(I).Item(k).Equals("1") = True Then
                count1 = count1 + 1
            End If
        Next k
    Next I

    If count1 > 7 Then  'output  = 10
       'do something
    End If
End Sub
```

Edit :

consecutive count from month 5 column 11 to month 6 column 1-5

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Id  | month | 1  | 2  | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
kek | 5     | 1  | 0  | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  0 | 1  |  1 |  1 |  1 |
kek | 6     | 1  | 1  | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  0 | 0  |  0 |  0 |  0 |
```

Comment: I don't see what the point of `find_rows` is. Why aren't you just using `dt.Rows(I)` instead?

Comment: I realized there is redundancy in my code and i have edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you seem to be trying to get the number of consecutive cells that have a value of `1`. If so, you can simply reset the value of `count1` whenever the cell's value is not `1`:

```
If dt.Rows(I).Item(k).ToString() = "1" Then
    count1 += 1
Else
    count1 = 0
End If
```

If you want to keep the latest consecutive `1` values even if followed by zeros, you can do something like this:

```
Dim latestConsecutiveCount As Integer
If dt.Rows(I).Item(k).ToString() = "1" Then
    count1 += 1
Else
    latestConsecutiveCount = count1
    count1 = 0
End If

If latestConsecutiveCount > someValue Then
    ' Do something
End If
```

Comment: Wouldn't that result in 0 for a row like 1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0 then?

Comment: @CharlesMay That's right but that seems to be what the OP wanted: _"I wanted to check the condition if the **latest columns** have total count of more then 7"_.

Comment: Yep, you're right, I didn't catch that and thought any 7 consecutive. Sorry.

Comment: The OP seems to want the count of *latest* defined by id - so you'd have to modify your code to order by id, then start at the end and work back until it encounters a '0'

Comment: thanks @AhmedAbdelhameed , sorry for bothering you but i have one last question, what should i do if i want the consecutive row count continue from one row to another row ?

Comment: @Vanquisher Do you mean rows or columns? Because your original question was about columns.

Comment: i have edited my question, sorry for the inconvenience caused.

Comment: @Vanquisher Edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks! I get what you mean, it is also applicable to the combination of current row and next row's column count right?

Comment: @Vanquisher Yes, it should. Because in your code, you're iterating both the rows and the columns. Good luck!